# Is 25% aqueous ammonia solution considerably less safe than concentrated HCl

Tags: home-experiment, safety

I plan to sterilize and clean some deer bones for display in my amateur chemical lab. The needed concentration of ammonia is only about 2,5% but it would be significantly cheaper to buy more concentrated solution, and dilute it myself. I have worked with NaOH, and concentrated HCl before, but I'm wondering will this be a bigger safety concern, and should I risk it just to save some money. I will obviously be working outside, with a fan running and wearing proper PPE (faceshield, googles, nitrlie gloves and a lab coat)

Comment: Well, no, I wouldn't say so. Why ask that?

Comment: Even HCN can be safe and water dangerous, depending on circumstances. Concentrated ammonia with proper handling of liquid volatile chemical is rather annoying due its famous smell than dangerous. I would suggest to partially dilute it as an intermediate stock solution.